# Why does `pub install` keep creating `packages` link in all the subdirs of `web`?

Tags: dart, package, dart-pub

I have a `web` dir, which contains some css and js files:

```
├── bootstrap-wysiwyg
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── packages -> ../../packages
│   └── republish.sh
├── css
│   ├── bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css
│   ├── packages -> ../../packages
│   ├── prettify.css
│   └── screen.css
├── images
│   └── packages -> ../../packages
├── js
│   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   ├── packages -> ../../packages
│   ├── prettify.js
│   └── prettify.js.1
├── lib
│   ├── font-awesome-3.2.1
│   └── packages -> ../../packages
└── packages -> ../packages
```

You can see there are one `packages` link in each subdir of the `web` dir. I deleted them once, but it will appear when I run `pub install`.

I can't understand why `pub` will create them for me, and is there any way to disable it? I don't want them because when I run `build` command in my IDEA Dart-plugin, it will reports errors since it can't handle them correctly.

Comment: Addtionally, it'S very anoying to have them in folders like "assets" or alike and you need to clean them up every time you deploy your project.

Comment: is it not just for easy referencing so everything is in `import 'package:fluff/fluff.dart'` regardless of what directory you are in?

Comment: Just an untested idea, but can't you add those folders to `.dartignore`?

Comment: Annoying with subversion on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Dart sees an import like:

```
import 'package:foo/foo.dart';
```

It translates it to:

```
import '<url of your entrypoint>/packages/foo/foo.dart';
```

So, say your app's entrypoint is in:

```
myapp/web/app/main.dart
```

If it has a "package:" import, like above, it will remap it to:

```
import 'myapp/web/app/packages/foo/foo.dart';
```

That means that for Dart to be able to find `foo.dart`, there needs to be a `packages` directory inside `app` that contains `foo/foo.dart`. Part of pub's job is to set that up for you.

This is definitely not the nicest part of working with Dart and pub. Spewing symlinks everywhere is gross, but it deals with the limitations that the language places on us. Over time, we're hoping to move away from having to create these symlinks.

More details on this [here](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/faq.html#what-are-all-the-packages-directories-for).

Comment: Regarding the your answer and question itself you are forgotten to explain about the the algorithm for calculating `<url of your entrypoint>` from different locations (directories)?

Comment: `<url of your entrypoint>` is either the argument you passed to the standalone Dart VM, or the URL in the `<script>` tag used to load your application.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I did not know that it's not working. `"myapp/bin/inside_bin/test_inside.dart"` because there is no `"packages/"` directory inside `"inside_bin/"`.